# Blender Crowd Sim Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've got this scene where I'm trying to get a crowd sim working over a terrain. However the cylinders I'm using as people randomly disappear and I'm not quite sure how to solve the issue. Has anyone had any experience doing this kind of thing with geometry nodes? I don't mind what the solution is it doesn't have to be at all what I'm doing but any help would be appreciated thanks.

Blend file:

https://pasteall.org/blend/6bdd82f697e748728b653953cd83f616

Comment: Hi Mitchell, i downloaded your file. But i cannot see any cylinder disappearing!? Did you change something in your blender file?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say when I move the plane around cylinders disappear

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer". This will make it easier for others to see which path leads to the solution, and the question will no longer show as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly a bit too late for you, but maybe it helps anyway:

The problem is that you first adjusted your grid to the terrain with a Shrinkwrap modifier, and made your point distribution on this deformed grid.

Since the Shrinkwrap modifier obviously changes the mesh in such a way that your point distribution also changes spontaneously in some places, your cylinders temporarily disappeared in some places.

**Solution (Blender 3+):**

If you do without the Shrinkwrap modifier, and first apply the node `Distribute Points on Faces` on your unchanged grid in the geometry nodes, the distribution always remains the same.

In the Geometry Nodes you can then use `Raycast` to find out the position of your randomly distributed points on the terrain and instantiate them there.

[image]